# Lattice object / modifier will not bend

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I added the Lattice object and modifier to a square tube object, went into edit mode, 'B' selected the nodes I wanted to try bending.. pulled them out.. and. Nothing.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Does the object which should be bent has enough loopcuts so to be bent ? And is lattice itself selected in **Lattice modifier** added for object to be bent ?

Comment: Yes. I think I already did that as you described. Here is the blend file: <img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=683" />

Comment: I edited your question to add the link to the blend which was broken. Feel free to make changes further on if this .blend is not yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your Lattice deformation to work:

1. First of all you have to subdivide a mesh at least with several loopcuts (and the more smooth transitions you want, the more subdivisions you need). To be concrete, exactly this wasn't done for your mesh in the file.
2. Then add a **Lattice Modifier** to your mesh, then select created lattice in the "Object" input box of the modifier.

Only after this is done, will modifications to the Lattice affect the mesh.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Alright, after taking a look a the blendfile, the reason for the modifier's misbehavior became clear: you simply don't have any subdivisions in your mesh, so it cannot bend. The lattice modifier affects existing geometry, and can only move existing vertices. As you can see in the gif below, after I added some subdivisions to the length of your mesh, using the Loop Cut and Slide Tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), the Lattice works fine.

[image]

Comment: Yes. I think I already did that as you described.  Here is the blend file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=683" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/683/)

Comment: I edited your answer to include only one extra step needed which wasn't done by OP. Other than that all the details are already added imo.

Comment: Alright, problem found using your blendfile, @Marc. See edited answer above.

Comment: Cool, thanks @MrZak (only saw this after my own edit, but still improves the original answer)